# failed to open stream: No such file or directory simple html dom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Currently I'm using SIMPLE_HTML_DOM to scrap some info. I've made a few sites but with one I've got a problem. Take a look on this site: 'http://www.prawo.uwb.edu.pl/prawo_new/news.php' When i use:

`$url = 'http://www.prawo.uwb.edu.pl/prawo_new/news.php';
 file_get_html($url);`

I get

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   .../simple_html_dom.php on line 75

, but I also checked on this site www.import.io page and worked fine.
I've read about `urlencode()` but without success.

Thanks for advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include what the value of $url is.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is probably disabled, meaning the url will be treated as a local file path, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryied with  curl way described on this [solution](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl) and function

`get_web_page` worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$url` is - is a link to some page.

You need to use ***system path*** for this function.

To get content from web page by it's url using [context parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Example:

```
$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header' => 'Accept-language: en\r\n'
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('http://your.site/', false, $context);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I guess that my link goes to .php file.

Comment: no, you need to pass the path like /var/www/... not url =)

Comment: But this is foreign site, not mine.